# How to draw a rectangle on a circular barplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a circular barplot generated by matplotlib. There are numerous tutorials online but they only cover regular 2D plots, the same code creates circles in circular bar plots rather than rectangles.

This is what I am trying to programmatically generate:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
axin = ax.inset_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1, 1])
axin.axis('off')
rect = patches.Rectangle((0.5, 0.25), 0.5, 0.25, linewidth=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
axin.add_patch(rect)
```

[image]